# Rails form in HAML syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Trying to create a file upload form using HAML in a Ruby on Rails application. Code is very small and straight forward:

```
= form_tag player_salary_path, :multipart=>true
  = file_field_tag :file
  = submit_tag "Import"
```

The error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to make it a `do...end` block. You need to add do to the end of the first line. See below:

```
= form_tag player_salary_path, :multipart=>true do
  = file_field_tag :file
  = submit_tag "Import"
```

Comment: Your answer help my problem. But still I feel weird when I must write `do` without `end`. Thanks anyway.